# How can I accomodate other signal handlers when trapping a signal?

Tags: ruby, process, signals

In Jesse Storimer's excellent book [Working With Unix Processes](https://www.jstorimer.com/products/working-with-unix-processes), he recommends this method for trapping signals while accommodating previous handlers:

```
old_handler = trap(:QUIT) {
  # do some cleanup
  puts 'All done!'

  old_handler.call if old_handler.respond_to?(:call)
}
```

This never exits itself. Presumably if a previous handler calls `exit`, that's fine. But what if there is no other signal handler, only the default one? My tests show that this means the process never exits, because the default one isn't provided by `trap` (`old_handler` will be the string `"DEFAULT"`).

From a previous example in the book while demonstrating something else:

```
old_handler = trap(:INT) {
  old_handler.call
  puts 'This is the second handler'
  exit
}
```

So if the `old_handler` calls `exit`, the program will exit and we will never need to. But if it doesn't, we will take care of `exit`. This seems fine. It's a bit odd that all handlers everywhere have to be responsible for possibly being the one to ultimately end the program, knowing that only exactly one of them will.

Anyway, assuming that that's true, here's what I've come up with as a pattern that can be universally used:

```
old_handler = trap("INT") do
  puts "doing something custom in response to INT"
  if old_handler.respond_to?(:call)
    puts "calling old handler for INT"
    old_handler.call
    exit # in case old_handler is a bad citizen
  else
    case old_handler
    when "DEFAULT"
      puts "done with custom handlers, exiting in response to INT"
      exit
    when "IGNORE"
      puts "done with custom handlers for INT, system default ignores it"
    else
      # in the case of EXIT it is nil. Not sure of other possibilities
      puts "old_handler is : #{old_handler.class}"
    end
  end
end
```

Is this a the correct way to go about this? Anything I'm missing?